# My SQL Count Problem

Tags: php, mysql, count, report

I have GENDER and Marital_status Column store data in integer value

Gender:

1. Male
2. Female

Marital Status:

1. Single
2. Widow
3. Married

I want to show a report how many Male and Female are in this table. also same as Marital Status.. i need a single query for this reporting.

Like, Count(Male) =100 and Count(female)=140 this.

Like, Count(married) =120, Count(single)=100 and Count(winddow)=10 this.

Please give me the Mysql/PHP solution.

## Column Data Detail..

| Gender | Marital Status |

```
1               2
1               3
2               2
2               1
```

Thanks,

Comment: Do you need two queries? or one for gender report, and a separate one for the marital status?

Comment: i try to use this but no luck `SELECT
COUNT(Gender) as Female
from personal
WHERE
Gender = 1 
UNION 
SELECT
COUNT(Gender) as Male
from personal
WHERE
Gender = 2`

Comment: okay if its done in two query then no problem..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A common trick is to use SUM instead of COUNT, and put an expression inside the SUM that is 1 on rows you want to count, 0 otherwise.  The SUM of 1's is equal to the COUNT of them.

```
SELECT
  SUM(Gender=1) AS Male_Count,
  SUM(Gender=2) AS Female_Count,
  SUM(Marital_status=1) AS Single_Count,
  SUM(Marital_status=2) AS Widowed_Count,
  SUM(Marital_status=3) AS Married_Count
FROM mytable;
```

In MySQL, a boolean expression (such as equality comparison) returns 1 or 0.  This isn't the case in standard ANSI SQL or in most other RDBMS implementations, so you'd have to write out longer `CASE` expressions if you want to support standards.

Answer (score 1):

```
select
sum(case when gender = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as male,
sum(case when gender = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as female,
sum(case when gender = 1 and status = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as male_singles,
.... and so on
from table
```

Answer (score 1):

are you about

```
 SELECT gender,status,count(*) FROM table GROUP BY gender,status
```